# Spawn and control second arm using OpenManipulator and MoveIt

Tags: python, c++, ros, moveit, gazebo-simu

I am currently working on a project where I spawn and control 2 arms independently in the same scene for a robot. I am going off of the OpenManipulator documentation/tutorials and using MoveIt to control their default arm, from this link:

http://emanual.robotis.com/docs/en/pl...

and

http://emanual.robotis.com/docs/en/pl...

So the idea is that, in a few different terminals, I am running the following commands to spawn a gazebo and rviz instance that are tied together, and I am able to use the provided GUI to manipulate a single arm or use code.

$ roslaunch open_manipulator_gazebo open_manipulator_gazebo.launch (spawns gazebo and robot arm with basic topics/nodes)

$ roslaunch open_manipulator_controller open_manipulator_controller.launch use_platform:=false (spawns rvis, with the same arm, and creates moveit controllers for the arm. I also modified this launch file to turn moveit to true)

$ roslaunch open_manipulator_control_gui open_manipulator_control_gui.launch (spawns provided gui)

I want to manipulate the launch files somehow to spawn a second arm that I can manipulate independently the same way I can control the first arm. I am finding no luck so far, and I am still working on the gazebo one. Not sure how I will go about the controller one that spawns rviz.

I manipulated the gazebo launch file as follows and was able to get 2 arms to show up, but not getting the topics or services to group separately or have their own unique names, or even spawn.

open_manipulator_gazebo.launch

```
    <launch>
  <!-- These are the arguments you can pass this launch file, for example paused:=true -->
  <arg name="use_robot_name" default="open_manipulator"
      doc="Must match the robotNamespace tag in the gazebo description file"/>
   <arg name="use_robot_name_2" default="open_manipulator_2"
      doc="Must match the robotNamespace tag in the gazebo description file"/>
  <arg name="paused" default="false"/>
  <arg name="use_sim_time" default="true"/>
  <arg name="gui" default="true"/>
  <arg name="headless" default="false"/>
  <arg name="debug" default="false"/>

  <!-- We resume the logic in empty_world.launch, changing only the name of the world to be launched -->
  <include file="$(find gazebo_ros)/launch/empty_world.launch">
    <arg name="world_name" value="$(find open_manipulator_gazebo)/worlds/empty.world"/>
    <arg name="debug" value="$(arg debug)" />
    <arg name="gui" value="$(arg gui)" />
    <arg name="paused" value="$(arg paused)"/>
    <arg name="use_sim_time" value="$(arg use_sim_time)"/>
    <arg name="headless" value="$(arg headless)"/>
  </include>



  <!-- Load the URDF into the ROS Parameter Server -->
  <param name="robot_description"
  command="$(find xacro)/xacro --inorder '$(find open_manipulator_description)/urdf/open_manipulator.urdf.xacro'"/>


<!-- Run a python script to the send a service call to gazebo_ros to spawn a URDF robot -->
  <node name="urdf_spawner" pkg="gazebo_ros" type="spawn_model" respawn="false" output="screen"
    args="-urdf -model open_manipulator -z 0.0 -param robot_description"/>


<!-- Load the URDF into the ROS Parameter Server -->
  <param name="robot_description_2"
  command="$(find xacro)/xacro --inorder '$(find open_manipulator_description)/urdf/open_manipulator.urdf.xacro'"/>


<!-- Run a python script to the send a service call to gazebo_ros to spawn a URDF robot -->
  <node name="urdf_spawner_2" pkg="gazebo_ros" type="spawn_model" respawn="false" output="screen"
    args="-urdf -model open_manipulator_2 -y 1.0 -param robot_description_2"/>

 <!-- ros_control robotis manipulator launch file -->
   <include file="$(find open_manipulator_gazebo)/launch/open_manipulator_controller.launch">
      <arg name="use_robot_name" value="$(arg use_robot_name)"/>
      <arg name="use_robot_name_2" value="$(arg use_robot_name_2)"/>
    </include>


</launch>
```

open_manipulator_controller.launch (the one in the open_manipulator_gazebo package, not open_manipulator_controller package. this one is called by the above launch file)

```
    <launch>
  <arg name="use_robot_name" />
  <arg name="use_robot_name_2" />
        <!--default="open_manipulator"-->

  <group ns="/robot_1">
  <!-- Load joint controller configurations from YAML file to parameter server -->
  <rosparam file="$(find open_manipulator_gazebo)/config/open_manipulator_controller.yaml" command="load"
           ns="$(arg use_robot_name)"/>

   <!-- load the controllers -->
  <node name="controller_spawner" pkg="controller_manager" type="spawner" respawn="false"
 output="screen" ns="$(arg use_robot_name)" args="joint_state_controller
                                              joint1_position
                                              joint2_position
                                              joint3_position
                                              joint4_position
                                              gripper_position
                                              gripper_sub_position"/>

   <!-- Run gripper sub position publisher -->
  <node name="gripper_sub_publisher" pkg="open_manipulator_gazebo" type="gripper_sub_publisher" output="screen" ns="$(arg use_robot_name)"/>

  </group>

  <group ns="/robot_2">

   <!-- Load joint controller configurations from YAML file to parameter server -->
  <rosparam file="$(find open_manipulator_gazebo)/config/open_manipulator_controller.yaml" command="load"
           ns="$(arg use_robot_name_2)"/>

    <!-- load the controllers -->
  <node name="controller_spawner_2" pkg="controller_manager" type="spawner" respawn="false"
 output="screen" ns="$(arg use_robot_name_2)" args="joint_state_controller
                                              joint1_position
                                              joint2_position
                                              joint3_position
                                              joint4_position
                                              gripper_position
                                              gripper_sub_position"/>
  <!-- Run gripper sub position publisher -->
  <node name="gripper_sub_publisher_2" pkg="open_manipulator_gazebo" type="gripper_sub_publisher" output="screen" ns="$(arg use_robot_name_2)"/>

  </group>


</launch>
```

This is where the original source code is from so you can compare it to the original launch files: https://github.com/ROBOTIS-GIT/open_m...

Any help would be appreciated. I am quite new to ROS, forgive me if I overlooked something simple. If I left out any important information let me know and I'll be happy to provide it.

Thank you for your time

Sincerely,

Alfred Shaker

Answer (score 0):

I'm also new to gazebo/ROS but in my project I spawn the robot from file and use the namespace to differenciate each /cmd_vel for example :

```
class GazeboEnvWithRobots(gazebo_env.GazeboEnv):
    def __init__(self):
        super(GazeboEnvWithRobots, self).__init__()
        number_of_robots = 1
        if rospy.has_param("NUMBER_OF_ROBOTS"):
            number_of_robots = rospy.get_param("NUMBER_OF_ROBOTS")
        for i in range(number_of_robots):
            self.robots.append(turtlebot3lidar.Turtlebot3Lidar("/tb3_" + str(i),i))
            rospy.logdebug("Robot " + str(self.robots[-1]) + " has been created")
```